# How to get the value of adjacent element and change it using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm facing issue in selecting an adjacent element and updating its value, I want to update the input value by clicking the -,+ buttons. I'm able to get all the buttons and looping through buttons adding onclick event listener to each button, I'm facing an issue in selecting (.amount value input) and updating it's value

```js
function decreaseAmount(step){
  const buttons=document.querySelectorAll(".input-amount button");
  buttons.forEach(function(button){
   button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   console.log(event.currentTarget.parentElement);
});
  });
}

function increaseAmount(step){
  const buttons=document.querySelectorAll(".input-amount button");
  buttons.forEach(function(button){
   button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   console.log(event.currentTarget.parentElement);
});
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="row break-none input-amount">
            <div class="col align-right">
                <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" onclick="decreaseAmount(10)">
                    <span>−</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col amount-value">
                <input id="amountvalue2135" type="number" value="1000" step="10" class="form-control">
               
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" onclick="increaseAmount(10)">
                    <span>+</span>
                </button>
                
                
                <div class="row break-none input-amount">
            <div class="col align-right">
                <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" onclick="decreaseAmount(10)">
                    <span>−</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col amount-value">
                <input id="amountvalue2135" type="number" value="1000" step="10" class="form-control">
               
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" onclick="increaseAmount(10)">
                    <span>+</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: When you click on the button for the first time, you execute your function which actually... adds eventlisteners on the button but do nothing.

Comment: @iguypouf yes, I'm adding another event listener in the script but that's not my issue, My issue when I double click the + or -, It should update the input  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, it's important with the javascripting to have good HTML structure. You had a row inside of a col.. I am not sure if that was intentional, but when you adapt the code in ths answer let me know if it doesn't fit with your structure.

Anyhow, the way I set this up is to put event listeners on all the buttons with the attribute `data-increment` which is something I added. You'll see the +10/-10 are in there. Then when you click a button, it knows how to get it's own increment. The button eventListener always has a single argument `event` (but you can call it whatever you want, I chose `e`). To find the input element relative to the button, I used `.closest()`. For instance this line:

```
let input = target.closest('.row').querySelector('input[type=number]')
```

This line says `input` = the `input type='number'` element that lives in the element with the class `row` that is the closest parent to me

You'll see many `+` before variables. This is shorthand to tell javascript to treat that variable as a number (since any html input element's value will always be a string)

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[data-increment]').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "button") target = e.target.closest('button');
    let inc = target.dataset.increment;
    let input = target.closest('.row').querySelector('input[type=number]')
    input.value = +input.value + +inc;
  })
})
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row break-none input-amount">
  <div class="col align-right">
    <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" data-increment="-10">−</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col amount-value">
    <input id="amountvalue2135" type="number" value="1000" step="10" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" data-increment="10">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row break-none input-amount">
  <div class="col align-right">
    <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" data-increment="-10"> − </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col amount-value">
    <input id="amountvalue2135" type="number" value="1000" step="10" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button class="app-action secondary" type="button" role="button" data-increment="10">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use JQuery, this is the simplified version

```js
$(function() {
  $(".minus").on('click', function() {
    let inputField = $(this).parent().find('input');
    let stepAmt = Number($(inputField).attr('step'));
    let currValue = Number($(inputField).val());
    $(inputField).val(currValue - stepAmt);
  });

  $(".plus").on('click', function() {
    let inputField = $(this).parent().find('input');
    let stepAmt = Number($(inputField).attr('step'));
    let currValue = Number($(inputField).val());
    $(inputField).val(currValue + stepAmt);
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row break-none input-amount">
  <button class="app-action secondary minus" type="button" role="button"> - </button>
  <input id="amount1" type="number" value="1000" step="10" class="form-control">
  <button class="app-action secondary plus" type="button" role="button"> + </button>
</div>

<div class="row break-none input-amount">
  <button class="app-action secondary minus" type="button" role="button"> - </button>
  <input id="amount2" type="number" value="1000" step="10" class="form-control">
  <button class="app-action secondary plus" type="button" role="button"> + </button>
</div>
```